# Долго выгружаются данные в из HTML в PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

Есть необходимость реализовать конвертор из HTML в PDF продукции. Все настроено все реализовано, но есть проблема, 25 страниц конвертируется за 75 секунд, что очень долго. Начал капать и вот что накопал,

Все фотографии продукт лежат в одной папке, их 16 000 фотографий. Если я беру одну фотографии и вывожу ее в html и сразу в Pdf то режим ожидания сокращается до 20 секунд что норм. Но если я в цикле вывожу каждую фотку то опять долго ждать приходиться. Думал может проблема в размере фотки, сжал их до минимума но все также. в чем может быть причина? неужели причина в том что он долго ищет нужную фотку из 16 000 файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно в вашем случае сложно сказать причину, но в зависимости от реализации скрипта и используемой файловой системы да, задержка из за большого количества файлов в папке возможна.

Именно чтобы избежать таких задержек и делают фрагментацию списка файлов по папкам. Как пример реализации, часто используемый, это класть файл в папку названную по первым двум буквам имени файла. В случае если имя файла представляет собой шестнадцатиричную строку и генерируется случайно, то будет создано ~256 папок, по которым файлы будут равномерно распределены. Как следствие "нагрузка" на отдельно взятую папку упадет в 256 раз. И поиск файла будет происходить быстрее.